# Cannot install datascience with python 2.7 - ValueError: This package requires python >= 3.0

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, data-science

My environment will not allow me to install datascience as it will no longer work with python 2.7. (worked ok a week ago).

I made the mistake of uninstalling anaconda and re-installing it to sort out an issue with plots. Seems my plan has backfired.

Can anyone out there advise how to access and install a previous version of datascience (scipy?) so I can get my assignment done?

The error message is below.

```
(env1) C:\Users\WeeP>pip install datascience
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting datascience
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/b4/df6f7fcf6c4ab4858c46e629769729af634e32455f84d8d3fafd8f4c90fa/datascience-0.15.6.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\GrantP\anaconda3\envs\env1\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\grantp\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-_ir4yh\\datascience\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\grantp\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-_ir4yh\\datascience\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'c:\users\grantp\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-_ir4yh\datascience\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: c:\users\grantp\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-_ir4yh\datascience\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\grantp\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-_ir4yh\datascience\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        raise ValueError('This package requires python >= 3.0')
    ValueError: This package requires python >= 3.0
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Some packages in Python are developed using certain version of Python. If you want to use that package, you must have at least the version of Python which was used to develop the package.

The same case is here in your question. Update Python 2.7 to at least Python 3.0 as `datascience` package requires at least Python 3.0. That can sort out your problem.

**Don't use deprecated packages or Python version**

Comment: Check for Python's latest release using ``conda search python``. Choose the version you want, for example ``3.5`` then run following command to install Python: ``conda install python=3.5``